# Base 64 field with file information to pass to WebService

Tags: c#, file, web-services, publish

:

I need to pass a zip file to a a target file of type byte[].
I am very new about web services.

I made the following in C# code:

```
string encodedStr = Utf16ToUtf8(@"c:\Users\joshepjohn\Test.zip");
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodedStr);
            string base64 = EncodeToBase64(encodedStr);
            request.message = System.Convert.FromBase64String((base64));
```

The documentaion of this web service said:
request.message = File with document data to import. It is the file itself that you want to import to the domain.
This file will be compressed in ZIP format. Within the SOAP message, the Base64-encoded ZIP file data will be sent within the envelope of the SOAP call.

I am confuse about SOAP message. Apart C# do I need to use another thing?.
The above code is right for documentation purposes?.

I made a try but the web service send a message: No file has been imported.

I hope that the zip file be imported to web service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a zip file as a base64-encoded SOAP message in C#, you need to do the following steps:

- Read the zip file as a byte array using the File.ReadAllBytes method.
- Convert the byte array to a base64 string using the
  Convert.ToBase64String method.
- Create a SOAP message using an XML document or a string builder. You
  can use a template or an example of a SOAP message that matches the
  web service specification. You can find some examples of SOAP
  messages in the web search results.
- Insert the base64 string into the SOAP message body, where the
  request.message element is expected. You can use the XmlDocument or
  XDocument classes to manipulate the XML elements, or you can use
  string concatenation or interpolation to insert the base64 string
  into the message.
- Send the SOAP message to the web service using an HttpClient or a
  WebClient object. You can use the PostAsync or UploadString methods
  to send the message and get the response.

Here is an example of C# code that follows these steps:

```
// Read the zip file as a byte array 
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@“c:\Users\joshepjohn\Test.zip”);

// Convert the byte array to a base64 string 
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

// Create a SOAP message using a string builder 
StringBuilder soapMessage = new StringBuilder(); soapMessage.Append(“<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>”); soapMessage.Append(“<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">”); soapMessage.Append(“soap:Body”); soapMessage.Append(“<request xmlns="http://www.example.com/webservice">”); soapMessage.Append(“<message>”); 

// This is where the base64-encoded zip file data goes     
soapMessage.Append(base64); 

// Insert the base64 string             
soapMessage.Append(“</message>”); soapMessage.Append(“</request>”); 
soapMessage.Append(“</soap:Body>”); soapMessage.Append(“</soap:Envelope>”);

// Send the SOAP message to the web service using an HttpClient 
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(“SOAPAction”, “http://www.example.com/webservice/import”); 

// This may vary depending on the web service 
HttpContent content = new StringContent(soapMessage.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, “text/xml”); HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(“http://www.example.com/webservice.asmx”, content); 

// This is the web service URL 
string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 

// This is the web service response
```

Comment: Hi!. Thank you for your prompt replay.

Comment: Another question. For create a project in C# Do I need to use an ASP.NET Web Application or I can use only A C# console application?

Comment: Hi, you're welcome, You can also use the console.

Comment: Hi! I am using WebClientObject

Comment: diwinIntegrationClient client = new EdiwinIntegrationClient(); This class have the method   publishDocument requiring user, password, etc. So, I need to create the SOAP request and after run this method?